# Resize PyTorch Tensor

Tags: python, runtime-error, pytorch, tensor, deprecation-warning

I am currently using the tensor.resize() function to resize a tensor to a new shape `t = t.resize(1, 2, 3)`.

This gives me a deprecation warning:

> non-inplace resize is deprecated

Hence, I wanted to switch over to the `tensor.resize_()` function, which seems to be the appropriate in-place replacement. However, this leaves me with an

> cannot resize variables that require grad

error.
I can fall back to

```
from torch.autograd._functions import Resize
Resize.apply(t, (1, 2, 3))
```

which is what tensor.resize() does in order to avoid the deprecation warning.
This doesn't seem like an appropriate solution but rather a hack to me.
How do I correctly make use of `tensor.resize_()` in this case?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use resize the tensor, not reshape? And if you want to resize it, is there anything you can archive with resize, what isn't possible by using slicing operations?

Comment: I think you have a point. Actually, now that you mention it I'm realizing that I probably should have used reshape in the first place. Here's the output of `t.size()` before and after the operation: torch.Size([16, 512, 8, 10, 2]) and torch.Size([16, 512, 8, 20])

Comment: Yes, so I think you can just use `view` or `reshape` (from version 0.4.0).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can instead choose to go with [`tensor.reshape(new_shape)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=reshape#torch.Tensor.reshape) or [`torch.reshape(tensor, new_shape)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.reshape) as in:

```
# a `Variable` tensor
In [15]: ten = torch.randn(6, requires_grad=True)

# this would throw RuntimeError error
In [16]: ten.resize_(2, 3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-094491c46baa> in <module>()
----> 1 ten.resize_(2, 3)

RuntimeError: cannot resize variables that require grad
```

---

The above `RuntimeError` can be resolved or avoided by using `tensor.reshape(new_shape)`

```
In [17]: ten.reshape(2, 3)
Out[17]: 
tensor([[-0.2185, -0.6335, -0.0041],
        [-1.0147, -1.6359,  0.6965]])

# yet another way of changing tensor shape
In [18]: torch.reshape(ten, (2, 3))
Out[18]: 
tensor([[-0.2185, -0.6335, -0.0041],
        [-1.0147, -1.6359,  0.6965]])
```

Comment: As already noted by @blue-phoenox  in the comments to the question, what I tried to achieve was indeed a reshape rather than a resize. I implemented the solution suggested here and it works just fine!

Comment: As a side-note: I used the `tensor.reshape()` function due to its easier readability!

Answer (score 1):

Please can you try something like:

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
print(":::",x.resize_(2, 2))
print("::::",x.resize_(3, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `t = t.contiguous().view(1, 2, 3)` if you don't really want to change its data.

If not the case, the in-place `resize_` operation will break the grad computation graph of `t`.
If it doesn't matter to you, just use `t = t.data.resize_(1,2,3)`.