# Resizing PyTorch tensor with grad to smaller size

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to downsize a tensor from let's say `(3,3)` to `(1, 1)`, but I want to keep the original tensor:

```
import torch

a = torch.rand(3, 3)
a_copy = a.clone()
a_copy.resize_(1, 1)
```

I need `requires_grad=True` in my initial tensor but PyTorch forbids this me from trying to resize the copy:

```
a = torch.rand(3, 3, requires_grad=True)
a_copy = a.clone()
a_copy.resize_(1, 1)
```

Throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytorch_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    a_copy.resize_(1, 1)
RuntimeError: cannot resize variables that require grad
```

### Clone and Detach

I tried to `.clone()` and `.detach()` as well:

```
a = torch.rand(3, 3, requires_grad=True)
a_copy = a.clone().detach()

with torch.no_grad():
    a_copy.resize_(1, 1)
```

which gives this error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytorch_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    a_copy.resize_(1, 1)
RuntimeError: set_sizes_contiguous is not allowed on a Tensor created from .data or .detach().
If your intent is to change the metadata of a Tensor (such as sizes / strides / storage / storage_offset)
without autograd tracking the change, remove the .data / .detach() call and wrap the change in a `with torch.no_grad():` block.
For example, change:
    x.data.set_(y)
to:
    with torch.no_grad():
        x.set_(y)
```

This behaviour had been stated in [the docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.Tensor.detach) and [#15070](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/15070).

### With `no_grad()`

So, following what they said in the error message, I removed `.detach()` and used `no_grad()` instead:

```
a = torch.rand(3, 3, requires_grad=True)
a_copy = a.clone()

with torch.no_grad():
    a_copy.resize_(1, 1)
```

But it still gives me an error about grad:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytorch_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    a_copy.resize_(1, 1)
RuntimeError: cannot resize variables that require grad
```

### Similar questions

I have looked at [Resize PyTorch Tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718045/resize-pytorch-tensor) but it the tensor in that example retains all original values.
I have also looked at [Pytorch preferred way to copy a tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266154/pytorch-preferred-way-to-copy-a-tensor) which is the method I am using to copy the tensor.

I am using PyTorch version 1.4.0

Comment: Have you tried first to detach and then clone: `a_copy = a.detach().clone()` ?

Comment: @AndreasK. No...I just tried it and it works

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should first detach and then clone:

```
a = torch.rand(3, 3, requires_grad=True)
a_copy = a.detach().clone()
a_copy.resize_(1, 1)
```

Note: `a.detach()` returns a *new* tensor detached from the current graph (it doesn't detach `a` itself from the graph as `a.detach_()` does). But because it shares storage with `a`, you also should clone it. In this way, whatever you do with the `a_copy` won't affect `a`. However I am not sure why `a.detach().clone()` works but `a.clone().detach()` gives error.

**Edit**:

The following code also works (which is probably a better solution):

```
a = torch.rand(3, 3, requires_grad=True)

with torch.no_grad():
    a_copy = a.clone()
    a_copy.resize_(1, 1)
```

Comment: @Moon Cheesez I have edited the answer. You can use `with torch.no_grad()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`narrow()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.narrow.html) function:

```
def samestorage(x,y):
    if x.storage().data_ptr()==y.storage().data_ptr():
        print("same storage")
    else:
        print("different storage")
def contiguous(y):
    if True==y.is_contiguous():
        print("contiguous")
    else:
        print("non contiguous")
# narrow => same storage contiguous tensors
import torch
x = torch.randn(3, 3, requires_grad=True)
y = x.narrow(0, 1, 2) #dim, start, len  
print(x)
print(y)
contiguous(y)
samestorage(x,y)
```

Out:

```
tensor([[ 1.1383, -1.2937,  0.8451],
        [ 0.0151,  0.8608,  1.4623],
        [ 0.8490, -0.0870, -0.0254]], requires_grad=True)
tensor([[ 0.0151,  0.8608,  1.4623],
        [ 0.8490, -0.0870, -0.0254]], grad_fn=<SliceBackward>)
contiguous
same storage
```